# PHP reverse the order of sub array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an array example I have.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

)
```

I need the order of the sub array to be reversed. I know the function I need to use is "reverse_array" but I do not know how to apply it to an array within an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you need to use is [`array_reverse()`](http://www.php.net/array_reverse), but I'm assuming that's the one you were talking about. To answer your question, you simply specify the array item instead of the main array:

```
$array[0] = array_reverse($array[0]);
//     ^                         ^
```

---

If you instead wish to reverse all sub-arrays in an array, you can use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/array_map):

```
$array = array_map('array_reverse', $array);
```